# How to execute code if div is in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scrollbar

I have already asked how to change the scrollbar color responsively, the answer was changing it when the section was at the bottom of the page. They said I could change the code to change the scrollbar color at different parts of the screen. I am wondering how I can do this but at the middle of the screen. This is the code I have so far (and yes I have researched and tried to find it out myself):

```
            let section1, section1Bounds, html;
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                section1 = document.getElementById('section1');
                section1Bounds = section1.getBoundingClientRect();
                html = document.documentElement;
                changeBarResponsive()
            });

            function windowOnLoadFunction() {
                section1 = document.getElementById('section1');
                section1Bounds = section1.getBoundingClientRect();
                html = document.documentElement;
                changeBarResponsive()
            };

            function changeBarResponsive() {
                window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
                    if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > section1Bounds.top) {
                        document.body.classList.add("changed");
                    } else {
                        document.body.classList.remove("changed");
                    }
                });
            }
```

Basically it is looking if the div "section1" is at the bottom of the screen or in the screen and changing the color from there. If you don't understand what I am talking about I will take the code snippet from his post before.
Note: The snippet was only working for Firefox, I changed it to work with Chrome but I don't know if it will still work with Firefox.

```js
let section1, section1Bounds, html;
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
   section1 = document.getElementById('section1');
   section1Bounds = section1.getBoundingClientRect();
   html = document.documentElement;
   changeBar()
});
window.onload = () => {
   section1 = document.getElementById('section1');
   section1Bounds = section1.getBoundingClientRect();
   html = document.documentElement;
   changeBar()
};
function changeBar() {
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
 if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > section1Bounds.top) {
    document.body.classList.add("changed");
    html.style.scrollbarColor = "blue purple";
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove("changed");
    html.style.scrollbarColor = "red green";
  }
});
}
```

```css
#section1 {
  font-size: 40pt;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1em;
  }
  body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(180, 88, 88, 0.473);
      background-color: rgb(131, 69, 69);
      scrollbar-width: auto !important;
  }
  body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    /* background-color: rgb(185, 115, 115); */
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #47c9da 0%, #25df91 100%);
    outline: 1px solid slategrey;
  }
  
  
  .changed::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(180, 88, 88, 0.473);
    background-color: rgb(131, 69, 69);
    scrollbar-width: auto !important;
}
.changed::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  /* background-color: rgb(185, 115, 115) !important; */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fa8313 0%, #da4646 100%) !important;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<h1> HEADER </h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br><br><br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<div id="section1"><p>Section 1</p></div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Now as you can see from the snippet above it changes the scrollbar color once the section is at the bottom of the page / in the page. I want to change this to change colors when near the middle of the screen and also when it is in the page normally.

I don't know if I explained this well but I hope I did. If you need more explanation please message me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using ```#section1``` as your trigger, entering the viewport, you want to wait until ```#section1``` is being halfway scrolled, or the window?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm quite new to JavaScript so I don't really know what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I assumed from you other question you were now asking how to make the scroll-bar change once the scroll bar ITSELF was in the middle. I update the code on you other post for that now. Once the document is scrolled halfway it will change. So if it was just a specific div then for the code above just change this to divide by 2 `if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight/2 > section1Bounds.top)` Now when section1 hits the middle of the page it will change. The other answer on the other post will change based on half the body hitting halfway on `window.innerHeight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for GSAP ScrollTrigger plugin, so much less hurdle for such tasks and it's free. You can control the end and the start points of the viewports to trigger your changes whenever you wish to.